# how to handel a submitted value in drupal form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I created a simple user form that allows the user to give a database name and when the user submitt the drupal site will be connected to the given databasename, I defined my database in the file settings.php: myDataBase and when I try

```
  db_set_active('myDataBase');
```

it works fine but when I type myDataBase in the text field and submitt and then use the submitted value  to connect to the database it didnt work.

```
<?php 
 function testform_menu() {
 $items = array();
 $items['test'] = array(
 'title' => 'connect an external database',
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 'page arguments' => array('testform'),
 'access callback' => TRUE,
 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 );

  return $items;
 }

 function testform($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $form['Databasename'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('enter the database name'),
   '#description' => t('a user interface to switch between databases'),
   '#size' => 28,
   '#required' => TRUE,

   );
 $form['submit'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => t('Submit'),
 );


  return $form;
}

function testform_validate($form, &$form_state) {

}

function testform_submit($form, &$form_state) {

if (db_set_active('myDataBase'))
{
    drupal_set_message('database connected'); // works
}

 //   $database_name =$form_state['values']['Databasename']; // ius not working!!
 //    if ($database_name ) {
 //    db_set_active($database_name); // I even tried to parsing the submitted value to a string but didnt work in both case
 //    drupal_set_message(t('connected to the database'.' '.$database_name));
 //    }
db_set_active();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to manage your form submit, for example:

```
function testform_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Or you can define the submit function using the `#submit` key in your form:

```
'#submit' => array('your_custom_function_name')
```

More info: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property

Inside this function you can process your form.

Comment: but it is already done : see my code for the function submitt it is only commented because it is not working.

Comment: One question, in your submit function if you harcode db_set_active(); with a string (not the one sended in the form) is working?

Comment: yes working but once I type the same string the text field the second once is not working